# Python functional programming reference to a constructor

Tags: python, constructor, functional-programming

I would like to have a function pointer `ptr` that can point to *either*:

- a function,
- the method of an object instance, or
- the constructor of the object.

In the latter case, the execution of `ptr()` should instantiate the class.

```
def function(argument) :
    print("Function called with argument: "+str(argument))

class C(object) :
    def __init__(self,argument) :
        print("C's __init__ method called with argument: "+str(argument))

    def m(self,argument) :
        print("C's method 'm' called with argument: "+str(argument))

## works
ptr = function
ptr('A')

## works
instance = C('asdf')
ptr = instance.m
ptr('A')

## fails
constructorPtr = C.__init__
constructorPtr('A')
```

This produces as output:

```
Function called with argument: A

C's __init__ method called with argument: asdf

C's method 'm' called with argument: A

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tmp.py", line 24, in <module>
    constructorPtr('A')

TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with C instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

showing that the first two ptr() calls worked, but the last did not.

Comment: `__init__` is an *instance method*, just like `m`, so needs to be called the same way(s).

Comment: As a side note, calling this a "pointer" is a little confusing. Functions, methods, classes, and everything else are values in Python; `ptr = function` is no more (or less) a pointer to a function than `ptr = 1` is a pointer to an int.

Comment: Why the downvote here? Because I was confused about something? :/ I did my best to make the question clear as I could.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) method isn't a constructor, it's an initializer.*

Notice that its first argument is `self`—that `self` has to be already constructed before its `__init__` method gets called, otherwise, where would it come from.

In other words, it's a normal instance method, just like `instance.m` is, but you're trying to call it as an unbound method—exactly as if you'd tried to call `C.m` instead of `instance.m`.

---

Python *does* have a special method for constructors, [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) (although Python calls this a "creator" to avoid confusion with languages with single-stage construction). This is a static method that takes the class to construct as its first argument and the constructor arguments as its other arguments. The default implementation that you've inherited from `object` just creates an instance of that class and passes the arguments along to its initializer.** So:

```
constructor = C.__new__
constructor(C, 'A')
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
from functools import partial
constructor = partial(C.__new__, C)
constructor('A')
```

---

However, it's incredibly rare that you'll ever want to call `__new__` directly, except from a subclass's `__new__`. Classes themselves are callable, and act as their own constructors—effectively that means that they call the `__new__` method with the appropriate arguments, but there are some subtleties (and, in every case where they differ, `C()` is probably what you want, not `C.__new__(C)`).

So:

```
constructor = C
constructor('A')
```

---

As user2357112 points out in a comment:

> In general, if you want a `ptr` that does `whatever_expression(foo)` when you call `ptr(foo)`, you should set `ptr = whatever_expression`

That's a great, simple rule of thumb, and Python has been carefully designed to make that rule of thumb work whenever possible.

---

Finally, as a side note, you can assign `ptr` to *anything* callable, not just the cases you described:

- a function,
- a bound method (your `instance.m`),
- a constructor (that is, a class),
- an unbound method (e.g., `C.m`—which you can call just fine, but you'll have to pass `instance` as the first argument),
- a bound classmethod (e.g., both `C.cm` and `instance.cm`, if you defined `cm` as a `@classmethod`),
- an unbound classmethod (harder to construct, and less useful),
- a staticmethod (e.g., both `C.sm` and `instance.sm`, if you defined `sm` as a `@staticmethod`),
- various kinds of implementation-specific "builtin" types that simulate functions, methods, and classes.
- an instance of any type with a `__call__` method,

And in fact, all of these are just special cases of the last one—the `type` type has a `__call__` method, as do `types.FunctionType` and `types.MethodType`, and so on.

---

<sub>* If you're familiar with other languages like Smalltalk or Objective-C, you may be thrown off by the fact that Python doesn't *look* like it has two-stage construction. In ObjC terms, you rarely implement `alloc`, but you call it all the time: `[[MyClass alloc] initWithArgument:a]`. In Python, you can pretend that `MyClass(a)` means the same thing (although really it's more like `[MyClass allocWithArgument:a]`, where `allocWithArgument:` automatically calls `initWithArgument:` for you).</sub>

<sub>** Actually, this isn't quite true; the default implementation just returns an instance of `C`, and Python automatically calls the `__init__` method if `isinstance(returnvalue, C)`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time finding the answer to this problem online, but I figured it out, so here is the solution.

Instead of pointing `constructorPtr` at `C.__init__`, you can just point it at `C`, like this.

```
constructorPtr = C
constructorPtr('A')
```

which produces as output:

```
C's __init__ method called with argument: A
```

Comment: Well, of course. You don't call `C.__init__` when you want a `C` instance; you call `C`. In general, if you want a `ptr` that does `whatever_expression(foo)` when you call `ptr(foo)`, you should set `ptr = whatever_expression`.

Comment: @user2357112: That's a nice summary.